# ASP: Repeater not working

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I've used [this](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-91-ASP.NET%20Tutorial.%20How%20to%20use%20Repeater) tutorial to use a repeater to display a list of names on a page on my project.

So I'm using dynamic data and in my aspx.cs page I have:

```
List<string> subContractors = new List<string>();

Context db = new Context();
subContractors = (from SUBContractors in db.BOQ_SubContractors
                  where SUBContractors.Bill_Of_Quantity_id == this.boqId
                  select SUBContractors.Sub_Contractor.Company_Name).ToList();
```

repeaterShowSubContractorName.DataSource = subContractors;
        repeaterShowSubContractorName.DataBind();

In my aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterShowSubContractorName" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="subContractors_ItemDataBound">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <asp:Label ID="SubConName" Text="SubContractor Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="SubCon" Text='<%# Eval("subContractors") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

The error is coming from `OnItemDataBound="subContractors_ItemDataBound"`.

What or where do I link this to? I have no `subContractors_ItemDataBound` at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just remove `OnItemDataBound="subContractors_ItemDataBound"` from your aspx page

**Edit** this error occurred because you don't have  `subContractors_ItemDataBound` method in .cs file to handle `OnItemDataBound` event , so you have to handle `OnItemDataBound` event  or just remove `OnItemDataBound="subContractors_ItemDataBound"`

**Edit** to bind list of strings use :

`<asp:Label ID="SubCon" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>`

Comment: thanks for reply i removed OnItemDataBound="subContractors_ItemDataBound but still no joy

Comment: @John try to add `repeaterShowSubContractorName.DataSource =subContractors;` `repeaterShowSubContractorName.DataBind();`

Comment: Is there any data returned to the repeater?

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat yes thank you I needed the data bind but now im getting an error as i am trying to bind a list of strings:                <asp:Label ID="SubCon" Text='<%# Eval("subContractors") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label> returning an error saying:DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'subContractors'.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough There is data in the table, but wont allow me to bind the string

Comment: @John replace  `'<%# Eval("subContractors") %>'` by `<%# Container.DataItem %>`

Answer (score 2):

Do this on your page load (or wherever you want to laod data) to link your data with repeater

```
    repeaterShowSubContractorName.DataSource = subContractors;
    repeaterShowSubContractorName.DataBind();
```

and remove

```
    OnItemDataBound="subContractors_ItemDataBound"
```

Comment: You need to do `repeaterShowSubContractorName.DataBind()` after setting the source. I have updated my answer with that. Also, is there any data in `subContractors`

Comment: yes thank you I needed the data bind but now im getting an error as i am trying to bind a list of strings: <asp:Label ID="SubCon" Text='<%# Eval("subContractors") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label> returning an error saying:DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'subContractors'.